# gnome-shell, for 2 simultaneous login users, is freezing a lot, when changing between them. How to workaround this?

Tags: gnome-shell

I frequently have to `pkill -SIGKILL "gnome-shell$"`, and wait about 1 or 2 minutes for gnome-shell to restart.
But I have to login on text (ctrl+alt+F5) to do that, as trying to go back to the other user takes a lot of time too.
Merely changing from one user to another takes about 10s to 15s, when gnome-shell do not freeze.

Lets call the two logins as L1 and L2.

Is there some way to make the inactive gnome-shell L1 behave properly while I am using the other login L2? I mean, is there some way to make L1 not bug when I came back to it?
May be SIGSTOP/SIGCONT on it? or something else?
Could there have some config to make it behave properly?
Any idea why this problem happens? is it related to the videocard?

I am asking for a workaround because I did update the system about 10 times already (I think), and the problem persists.

ubuntu 20.04